# Device to detect where heat or cold air is escaping or entering a structure

Tags: insulation, energy-efficiency, weatherstripping

I would like to lower my environmental impact and reduce my energy bills by reducing areas where air might be entering or exiting my home.

What type of device can be used to detect where heat or cool air is escaping or entering a home?

I would prefer the device be inexpensive, if possible.

Comment: Honestly, in the middle of winter, I use my hand to feel for cold drafts.  Just left a rental property where I did this along the stone foundation wall with a can of great stuff in the other hand.

Comment: @ssaltman That is certainly inexpensive! :)

Comment: MOE12 has the inexpensive answer. The expensive one is a FLIR or other thermal imaging camera. [Handheld standalone](http://www.amazon.com/FLIR-E4-Compact-Thermal-Resolution/dp/B00FKD9DSW/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1418395627&sr=8-2&keywords=flir+imager) versions start at about $1000, and it looks like [Android](http://www.amazon.com/Seek-UW-AAA-Thermal-Connector-Black/dp/B00NYWAHHM/ref=pd_sim_p_1?ie=UTF8&refRID=1HQWSD3P8HQCFV6GFGZW)/[IOS](http://www.amazon.com/FLIR-ONE-Thermal-Imager-iPhone/dp/B00K0PXFB6/ref=pd_sim_hi_4?ie=UTF8&refRID=1SX9HAQVE0TFB9R7V31R) plugins run from $200-300.

Answer (score 4):

A thermal imaging gun will show you all the hot and cold spots inside your house, but they are very expensive.

What I did was I purchased a infrared thermometer gun at my local harbor freight. It cost about $15.00 Then I went around took all the temperatures throughout the house.

I found in my basement the rim joists were not insulated, I also found my attic hatch was not insulated. After doing that and caulking the windows, the cost for the insulation and caulk paid for itself the first winter.

Comment: You may be able to rent one.

Comment: for rental, see, e.g., [here](http://www6.homedepot.com/tool-truck-rental/mobile/Thermal_Camera/FLIR_i7/) (promise I'm not advertising any particular service -- others please add other links of you know of them, this is just the first thing that popped up and was available in my area)

Answer (score 2):

A FLIR (infrared) or thermal imager is still the best way; you can rent them pretty easy and cheap, even at Home Depot http://www.flir.com/homedepot/

Comment: do you think 3 hours is a reasonable amount of time to be able to use the FLIR properly? HD near me offers a 4-hr rental, not sure I'll be able to image my whole apartment in that window.

Answer (score 1):

I have a FLIR camera. It's awesome, but it's expensive and not necessarily the best tool for detecting air leaks. An IR camera is too slow; you won't use it unless you have more dedication than most.

What you want is a fog machine. Turn it on inside the house, close all the windows but one, and put a box fan in that window blowing air *into* the house. This will pressurize the house and force the fog outside. You go outside and see where the fog is coming from. For an even more spectacular effect, get colored fog juice.